# Embed a windows media player in a web page during runtime in c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to embed windows media player in my own created web page. can any one please guide me how can i do it in c# and Asp.net. that also should be supported in all browsers.

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Comment: i have never seen anything like this..is it really possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to embed Windows Media Player on non-Windows browsers.

You should use the HTML5 `<video>` tag, with a Flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/embed_mediaplayer.htm). The procedure should be the same for ASP.NET also.

As SLaks suggested explore the HTML5 video tag option also. Both has its advantages and disadvantages, your target audience should drive which option you go with(if you have a lot of IE6/7/8 users, HTML5 wont work for them).

Comment: thanks for your comment, i tried your code, it is working fine in IE8 but your code doesn't work in mozilla firefox 4.0 and google chrome 10.0 versions windows media didn't open. can anyone help how can i work it in all three browsers.   thanks in advance,, Arun